# UI tabBar Controller

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

i have created a single application and then created 2 tabs programmatically, then i have created 2 buttons tab 1 and tab 2 here is the code of .m file

```
(IBAction)tab1:(id)sender { self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0; }
(IBAction)tab2:(id)sender { self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=1; }
```

here is the code of my appdelegate.m

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

// Override point for customization after application launch.
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

UIViewController *viewController1 = [[firstViewController alloc] init];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[secondViewController alloc] init];

self.tabBarController.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1,viewController2, nil];

//self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

return YES;
}
```

apparently there is no error in this code, if i set the tabbarcontroller as root it shows the tabs but when i want the viewcontroller to be root and buttons pointing to the tabs it doesnt work.

Comment: Please explain clearly, it's unclear what you are asking

Comment: basically im trying to create an application which has a single view controller having 4 buttons, i want to link these buttons with 4 different tabs, when user click button 1 the tab 1 opens similarly when user clicks button 2 tab 2 opens. i am going to add navigation controllers in it and some table view controllers but before that i need buttons to work
i tried to use self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0 but it doesn't work

Comment: so can't you implement this using xib or storyboard?

Comment: i have tried that but its not working properly, segue created on a single buttons takes to the main tab page but when i connect the second button it takes to the 1st tab instead of taking me to 2nd tab

Comment: can you send me your code?

Comment: what is your email address ?

Comment: Aah! I mean share your code here with SO that how do you relate tabbarcontroller with buttons or detailed explanation with xib steps. And if you are not able to elaborate this then share your code over some special coding site.

Comment: i have shared my code in the question what else do you want ?
you are not helping

Comment: If the buttons you wish to use are not the UITabBarItem type, then you should set up an IBAction and when you call that IBAction you only need to do self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = integerValue; if you want to allocate a UITabBarController in code and wish to use the buttons as the tab, then you will need to manually allocate new TabBarItem Instances,

Comment: UITabBarItem* item1 = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Some Title" image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"some image"] tag:someTag];

    UITabBarController* tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    [tabBarController setTabBarItem:item1];

Answer (score 0):

Hide default tabbar of tabbarviewcontroller by using bellow code

```
[[self tabBarController] setTabBarHidden: YES];
```